# Display centralized text under qrcode in PDF file

Tags: python-3.x, string, pdf, qr-code, reportlab

I'am trying to extract some informations from PDF file, then create qrcode and display it on same pdf with some text under this qrcode, the problem is I couldn't centralized a text just under a qrcode b-cause unit size is not unique for page size, qrcode size and text width.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab_qrcode import QRCodeImage
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import stringWidth

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize

### Paramètres ##########
x = 180.0
y = 600.0
size = 10
font_size = 7
text_to_be_centralized = 'Some text'
can = Canvas('multi_pages.pdf')
qr2 = QRCodeImage('Some information from original PDF', size=size * mm, fill_color=(1, 0, 0))
qr2.drawOn(can, x+28.34, y+28.34)
can.setFont("Times-Roman", font_size)
can.drawString(0, y-7, text_to_be_centralized)
string_width = can.stringWidth(text_to_be_centralized)
print('defaultPageSize : ', defaultPageSize)
print('string_width : ', string_width)
```

Output of size page and string is :

```
page = (595.275, 841.8897)
string_width = 1197....
QR_code_size = 10*10*mm
```

There is no relation between this sizes, I tried input a text with same size of my page and print string_width but the result was 1200.

Comment: @KJ the problem that they have no same unit size

Comment: it doesn't work for me, b-coz I tried and tried and same problem, I think I need to define unit size for each thing (page, qrcode, text), but I didn't know how to.

Comment: You're about mm and chat in point, but we need to page size in point.